# Use django-bouncer without deprecated hashcompat

Tags: django

I'm using django-bouncer to create a waiting list on a Django 1.6 app. Unfortunately, it looks like django-bouncer relies on hashcompat, which was deprecated for 1.6, because I'm getting this:

```
  File "/Users/michelleglauser/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bouncer/models.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.utils.hashcompat import sha_constructor
```

Is there a way for me to get around this besides by going back to an earlier version of Django?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Open https://github.com/shelfworthy/django-bouncer/blob/master/bouncer/models.py.

Copy the code (it's been updated for Django 1.6).

Find the bouncer folder in your site-packages.

Open models.py in your text editor.

Replace the text with the copied code and save.

Comment: I would recommend installing django-bouncer directly from that fork of the project, rather than editing the file on your local machine.  The advantage of installing it from the fork is that you will be able to put the address of the fork in your requirements.txt file when you want to deploy your completed project.

Comment: Sounds even better. Could you tell me how? I just installed it with pip install django-bouncer, so I'm not sure how to get that specific fork.

Comment: You can install directly from git (see https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git for details), but it's faster to take advantage of Github's archive service.  Try simply `pip install https://github.com/shelfworthy/django-bouncer/archive/master.tar.gz`?  I think that will work -- if not, you could try one of the git examples from the documentation.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it that way, and it installed just fine, but for some reason Heroku isn't picking up the new version and is still throwing the "No module named hashcompat" error. Do you know what I can do? Should I open a new question?

Comment: Here's my new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558725/heroku-not-picking-up-updated-django-bouncer-package