# Heroku not picking up updated django-bouncer package

Tags: django, heroku

I had an old version of django-bouncer that required hashcompat, which is now deprecated. Since I was getting errors telling me this, I did `pip uninstall django-bouncer`, then installed the version upgraded for Django 1.6 (it uses hashlib instead of hashcompat) using `pip install https://github.com/shelfworthy/django-bouncer/archive/master.tar.gz` (I also re-added it to my requirements.txt file).

Locally, this is working fine. However, when I push to Heroku, I'm still getting the error "No module named hashcompat."

I tried doing a `git push heroku master --force`, but that didn't resolve the problem. Then I reset the app by doing `heroku repo:reset -a <myappname>`, followed by did a new git push heroku master. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error on my Heroku app.

How can I make Heroku get the upgrade of django-bouncer?

Comment: Can you post your `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is this:

- Firstly, install django-bouncer's latest release locally on your laptop (you can do this by running `pip install -U django-bouncer`.
- Next, figure out what the latest version is on your laptop, by running: `pip freeze | grep django-bouncer`. You should see something like: `django-bouncer==x.x.x`.
- Lastly, edit your project's `requirements.txt` file and add `django-bouncer=x.x.x`, then push this change to Heroku. This will force Heroku to detect what *specific* version of django-bouncer is required, and install it for you.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you are running afoul of Heroku's package cache; it sees django-bouncer is already installed and doesn't bother to install it again.  But, you can't uninstall it either.

I recall there's a bit of a hack to get around this: Heroku will wipe out its package cache if you change the version of Python you are using.  So if you are using, say, 2.7.6, edit your [runtime.txt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) to change it to `python-3.4.0`.  If you are already using a 3.x branch, do the opposite.  It's not important that your application actually works on the version you're changing it to -- deploy once, and change it back.  That *should* wipe out your package cache entirely, at which point you'll be good to go.